# Is it possible to use an external hard drive for Raspberry Pi & Xbox One?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, storage, retropie, media

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B to use as an entertainment center (with Retropie for playing roms & Kodi for playing media). I have an external harddrive that I'd like to store my roms on & permanently mount for the Pi, but I currently use it to store some movies on for my Xbox One & I'd like to continue to do that as well. I know Pi runs on a variation of Linux so I wasn't sure if this was even possible. Is there a way to partition my external harddrive or just have a separate movie folder that the Xbox would still be able to read? The harddrive is currently formatted in a Windows format, & Xbox works with it like its just a media device (not formatted to store Xbox One games & such).

Comment: Is the hard drive connected to the Pi with the XBox accessing the Pi to get at the movies or the other way around? Linux can read Windows formatted drives/partitions

Comment: Currently the harddrive is only hooked up to the Xbox. I haven't even hooked it up to the Pi yet to see what would happen. I assumed the Pi would have to reformat it to work with it, but I wasn't sure if Windows would then be able to read the drive anymore so that I could still access files (ie movies, music, etc) on it, so that I could use the drive for both my Xbox & my Pi as needed

Comment: Linux can read NTFS.  I think it is slower than extfs and more CPU intensive,  but the Pi 2 should be able to playback media at the same time without any problems.

Comment: So are you saying that, if all I need by external harddrive for is playing media from & storing roms on, I should just leave it hooked up to the Pi & let IT play back my media, instead of swapping back & forth between the 2? If I instead keep the format of the harddrive on NTFS so that Windows AND Linux can both read it, would it become difficult to play roms from, or should the Pi 2 B still be able to run them with no lag? OR is there a way for Windows to read extfs if I format it with the Pi?

Comment: Based on this site: http://www.htpcguides.com/raspberry-pi-2-vs-banana-pi-ext4-vs-ntfs-vs-exfat/  NTFS doesn't really seem to hindered the Pi2 much as far as FTP, so I wouldn't think it would be hinder much when accessing the harddrive directly through a USB connection either; but I'm no expert by any means so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can read NTFS in Linux, install ntfs-3g package. I assume you are using raspbian.

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g <external hard drive> <target dir>
```

also you can create permanent mount point in /etc/fstab with device UUID.

Comment: He uses retropie, which is based on raspbian (as I understand it) so there is little need to assume. And `ntfs-3g` allows both R/W access.